# Flask Code Doesn't Make Sense (To Me)

Tags: python-2.7, flask, flask-login

I'm reading Miguel Grindberg's great new book "Flask Web Development", and don't understand part of this code on page 107. . .

```
@auth.before_app_request
def before_request():
    if current_user.is_authenticated() \
            and not current_user.confirmed \
            and request.endpoint[:5] != 'auth.':
        return redirect(url_for('auth.unconfirmed'))
```

I do not understand what the purpose of the slice ([:5]) is in the line. . .

```
and request.endpoint[:5] != 'auth.':
```

Here's his explanation for the code. #3 is referring to the line in question.

**"The before_app_request handler will intercept a request when three conditions are
true:
1. A user is logged in (current_user.is_authenticated() must return True).
2. The account for the user is not confirmed.
3. The requested endpoint (accessible as request.endpoint) is outside of the authentication
blueprint. Access to the authentication routes needs to be granted, as
those are the routes that will enable the user to confirm the account or perform
other account management functions."**

My question is, why the slice ([:5])? To me it seems the code would match his explanation perfectly without the slice. He says the purpose is to catch any endpoint outside of "auth", so it seems to me the code should be. . .

```
and request.endpoint != 'auth.':
```

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`request.endpoint` is a string. It has no knowledge about blueprints and views. The slice is there because `request.endpoint` contains more than just `'auth.'`, for example `'auth.unconfirmed'`. This could also have been written as `request.endpoint.startswith('auth.')`.

`request.endpoint != 'auth.'` will always evaluate to true because there will never be an endpoint with that name. If you tried to evaluate `url_for('auth.')` you'd get a `BuildError`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think I see your point, but I still have some confusion on the slice. If request.endpoint is a string which I understand, and it can be various lengths as per your example, how can you possibly know what slice to use? In other words, how does he know to use the slice ([:5]) when the string request.endpoint could be any length? There's something I'm obviously missing on this subject, lol.

Comment: Oh wait, I think I see. . .the slice is [:5] because "auth" is 4 letters and with that slice it can't ever evaluate to "auth", it must evaluate to whatever is after "auth"? Is this what your trying to say, lol, I hope?

Comment: Ok, I see now. My problem was I didn't quite understand the contents of `Request.endpoint`. Again, THANKS to everyone who answered.

Answer (score 3):

`request.endpoint` holds data like `auth.unconfirmed` or `main.whatever`

the code here is a check for the blueprint part (in this case"auth.")

after line
`return redirect(url_for('auth.unconfirmed'))`

was executed, this whole code block gets called again (request.endpoint having the value 'auth.unconfirmed', without the slice this would be a infinite loop)

Long story short: do not redirect if in auth blueprint

**Concerning your comment:**
from the doc:

> @before_app_request
>
> Such a function is executed before *each* request,
>   even if outside of a blueprint.

So after `return redirect(url_for('auth.unconfirmed'))` the block is called again (**new request**), but now request.endpoint is the string 'auth.unconfirmed'. Then `request.endpoint[:5] != 'auth.'` is false and then there is no further redirect (otherwise there would be the endless loop)

Comment: Thanks for the help, unfortunately I still don't get why the slice is there or exactly what it does. You say after the redirect to (url_for('auth.unconfirmed')), "the whole code block gets called again." Why? Why wouldn't it just redirect to the view "auth.unconfirmed" and go from there?

Comment: Redirects are handled by the browser, not the server. When you return a redirect from a view, the browser received an HTTP status code telling it where to redirect. The browser then makes a new request for that address.